# How to validate two specific lengths - Reactive forms

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I am doing a field validation in Angular component. There is a one field like it should allow to enter either 6 or 8 length of any characters. Usually minLength(6), maxLength(8) will work if it is 6 to 8 in between but length 7 should not allow here. I can do custom validation, but out of curiosity I'm looking is there any way to handle this kind of scenario. Thanks in advance.

```js
'myField': ['', [Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(8)]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way without a custom validator I can think of is `Validator.pattern` , which takes a regular expression. Something like that:

```
myControl: FormControl = new FormControl(undefined, [
    Validators.pattern('^.{6}$|^.{8}$'),
  ]);
```

Or for only alphabetical:

```
myControl: FormControl = new FormControl(undefined, [
    Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]{6}$|^[a-zA-Z]{8}$'),
  ]);
```

Comment: Wow..Thanks it is working as expected ..And if i want to add it should allow only Alphabetical to that regex, how can i add

Comment: Instead of the dot, use `[a-zA-Z]`. Extended my answer for that

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm , what will be the regex for numeric entry only. I tried this   
 ('^[0-9]{6}$|^[0-9]{8}$') but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a custom validator for your case; you can use pattern Validators.

```
'myField': ['', [Validators.pattern('^(?=(?:.{6}|.{8})$).*$')]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer And if i want to add it should allow only alphanumeric characters to that regex, how can i add

Comment: @Roy change the regex to this:
^(?=(?:.{6}|.{8})$)[a-zA-Z]*$

Comment: And one last help, how to create such regex, is there any reference..Thank you :)

Comment: This site https://regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

you can use a custom validators with a between function like that  :

```
function between(x, min, max) {
  return x >= min && x <= max;
}


function ratingRange(min: number, max: number): 

    ValidatorFn {
      return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
        if (c.value !== null && (isNaN(c.value) || c.value < min || c.value > max) || this.between(c.value , min , max)) {
          return { range: true };
        }
        return null;
      };
    }
```

then :

```
 'myField': [null, ratingRange(6, 8)],
```